# BottomSheetDialogFragment goes behing NavigationBar on new ViewPager fragment swap

Tags: android, kotlin, stripe-payments, android-constraintlayout, android-bottomsheetdialog

My `BottomSheetDialogFragment` starts out fine -- you can see it is floating above the navigation bar.

[image: Starting view]

When I click continue and the new view is swapped in, the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` expands behind the navigation bar. I can swipe to pull the view up over the bar.

[image: Two buttons behind navigation bar]

The issue

Here is how it looks if I pull the view up with my finger.

[image: Used my finger to slide the bottomsheet dialog fragment up]

I feel like I have narrowed the issue down to the `com.stripe.android.view.CardFormView` as if this view is removed, for testing purposes, the view is fine. It is only when

```
  <com.stripe.android.view.CardFormView
            android:id="@+id/card_form_view"
            style="@style/StripeCardFormView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

is visible that the other buttons are pushed out of alignment.

I have several other views in this BottomSheetDialog and this view is the only one that is maligned.

How can I get the sheet to reset itself when it is loaded?

---

```
class TPCollectPaymentDialog() : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: BottomSheetDialogBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetDialog)
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = BottomSheetDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.viewPager2.orientation = ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL
        binding.viewPager2.adapter = TPStandardFlowPageAdapter(this)
        binding.viewPager2.isUserInputEnabled = false
    }



    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

**bottom_sheet_dialog.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_dialog_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ManualEntryFragment.kt**

```
class ManualEntryFragment : Fragment(), BluetoothReaderListener {
    private var _binding: CardManualPaymentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = CardManualPaymentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.tvErrorMessage.remove()
        binding.progressBar.remove()
        binding.btnCancel.show()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.root.requestLayout()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

**manual_card_fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

      // other elements removed for brevity

        <com.stripe.android.view.CardFormView
            android:id="@+id/card_form_view"
            style="@style/StripeCardFormView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCheckout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the guide you referenced which suggests using `CardFormView`? The latest guides suggest using either the [mobile Payment Sheet](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#android-collect-payment-details) or the [Card Element/CardInputWidget](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=custom#android-create-checkout-page). You may want to try the `CardInputWidget` in this case. Otherwise, I'd suggest making a minimal repro repo and filing an issue on [stripe-android](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues)